# Ubuntu is looking for my credentials on local server and not locally during login etc

Tags: sudo, login-screen, webserver

The login process is really slow and when I use sudo the same. From what I have seen, the system tries to find my credentials first on the server and then locally, on my machine. Any way to change the order?

When I remove the internet connection, both login and sudo commands runs as expected. I tried edited the /etc/nsswitch.conf file but no luck.

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Jos Sorry about that, if possible delete one of them!

Comment: You will need to give us more information...what kind of "local server" does your machine try to connect to? What is installed on your system that makes it look for another server in the first place?

Comment: At school we use one that has username/password credentials but on my machine I use the local user/pass. Frankly I have no idea whats installed, the only thing that was suggested to me to do was to edit the  cat /etc/nsswitch.conf and for 2-3 days nothing happed but suddenly the login/sudo speed is back to normal. I have also checked host/hostname and both of them have localhost

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean. Is it the same computer that you take to school and is supposed to join an Active Directory there or something? Or are we talking about two different computers? A straight Ubuntu install will not try to connect to an external server for authentication.

Comment: Yeah I know that I don't make much sense, I'm new at Ubuntu Sorry. Let me explain one more time, at school there is a computer that runs Ubuntu has a username and a password. Last week they made a change in order to login using my school credentials and have access to the school storage at nick@school.com (example). After this change the login was really slow and so were the sudo commands. When I removed the Internet connection everything worked fine. Hope I made sense this time